# Does the Opial's condition always hold in finite dimension Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The Opial's condition is the following:

A Banach space $X$ is said to satisfy Opial condition if for each sequence ${x_n}$ in $X$ the condition $x_n \xrightarrow{w} x $ implies that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{sup} ||x_n-x||<\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{sup} ||x_n-y||$$
for all $x\neq y$.

---

This condition should be always valid if a finite dimensional Banach spaced is considered, can someone help me with the demonstration?
Thank you in advice

Comment: Can you show that, in a finite-dimensional Banach space, weak and norm convegence are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is finite dimensional, then $x_n \xrightarrow{w} x \iff ||x_n-x|| \to 0$,

hence, if $x_n \xrightarrow{w} x $ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{sup} ||x_n-x||=\lim_{n \to \infty}||x_n-x||=0$

Now let $y \ne x$ and suppose that  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{sup} ||x_n-y||=0$. Then we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}||x_n-y||=0$ (why ?)

This gives $y=x$ a contradiction. Hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathrm{sup} ||x_n-y||>0$.